# Timelessness in scriptures

Tags: scripture, time

In Hinduism, time is generally called as KAla.

Is there any mention in any scripture about the existence of **timelessness**. I mean where kAla does not exist.

Comment: There's nothing except KAALA. KAALA is Shiva. KAALA is Bhairava. KAALA is everything.

Comment: Nasadiya sukta says - Then even nothingness was not, nor existence,
There was no air then, nor the heavens beyond it. (RV 10.129).   I think, it indicates Timelessness :-) @hanugm

Comment: Nirguna Brahman is timelessness. There is no time, no awareness of time in Nirguna Brahman.

Comment: Time does not exist in the spiritual plane. So on the planet of brahman there no time.

Comment: The yoga vasistha might be a good candidate scripture to search for this concept. Only issue is, it is a long scripture.

Answer (score 3):

The primary purpose of the Veda is the sacrifice. These sacrifices are executed according to a predetermined time. Therefore, Vedāṅga Jyotish of Lagahda exists and it provides information to determine the time for performance of the Vedic sacrifices. It categorically says that Vedas are for sacrifice (2.3).

> vedā hi yajnñārthamabhipravṛttāḥ kālānupūrvā vihitāśca yajñāḥ
>
> tasmādidaṃ kālavidhānaśāstraṁ yo jyotiṣa vedaṁ sa veda yajñān

**Hence, the concept of timelessness does not exist in the Vedic scriptures.**

However, in the mythology of Upanishads literature, one can find the concept of timelessness.

For instance, Maitrī Upanishad it is stated that the two forms of the  Brahman are time and timelessness (6.15)

> द्वे वाव ब्रह्मणो रुपे कालश्चाकालश्चाथ यः प्रागादित्यात्सोऽकालोऽकालोऽथ

It further also states that the time has form and formlessness (6.14)

> काले चास्तं नियच्च्हन्ति कालो मूर्तिरमूर्तिमान्

Comment: Good reference from the upanishad.